# Cosmetic error on advanced help screen

Tags: bug, design

If you visit the [advanced help screen](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on stackoverflow and scroll to the bottom of the page, you can see the side menu overlaps the footer section.

**Screen shot from Firefox 27**

> [image]